# Min-cost flow with per-edge flow conservation

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, network-flow

I am trying to solve a linear program that is identical to a min-cost flow problem, except for a difference in the flow-conservation constraint.

Instead of the summed outgoing flow equaling the summed incoming flow for each node:
$$\sum_i f_{i,n} = \sum_j f_{n, j}  \ \forall n$$
The flow **of each outgoing edge** should equal the summed incoming flow for each node:
$$\sum_i f_{i,n} = f_{n, m}  \ \forall n, m$$

In other words: The incoming flow is replicated along all outgoing edges.

I wonder if:
1.) This problem has a particular name in the literature
2.) It has an optimal integral solution when all edge capacities are integral

Comment: Are you sure about the definition of per-edge flow conservation? This would result in increasing the total flow while traversing the network from the origin to the destination. Suppose the incoming flow to a node is 100 and there are five outgoing edges from that node. Based on your constraint, the total outgoing flow would be 500.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a well-studied problem close to your one: [Integral Flow With Multipliers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2293355/flow-problem-with-multiplicative-nodes). It was proved to be NP-hard in [the seminal Sartaj Sahni's paper](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/%7Esahni/papers/computationallyRelatedProblems.pdf) in computational complexity theory (see section 2.2 of the paper). Another interesting, more recent paper can be found [here](http://e-archive.informatik.uni-koeln.de/589/2/zaik2009-589.pdf).